# Laravel doesn't set oracle as connection

Tags: database, laravel, oracle, config

I've some troubles setting oracle connection for laravel.
This is what i did:

1. Modified .env with properly settings, removing `DB_CONNECTION="mysql"`and replacing it with `ORACLE_CONNECTION="oracle"`
2. Modified database.php with properly settings:

   ```
   'default' => env('ORACLE_CONNECTION', 'oracle'),
   ```

   'connections' => [

   ```
   'mysql' => [
       'driver' => 'mysql',
       'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
       'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
       'database' => env('DB_NAME', 'simone'),
       'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
       'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
       'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
       'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
       'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
       'prefix' => '',
       'prefix_indexes' => true,
       'strict' => true,
       'engine' => null,
   ],

   'oracle' => [
       'driver' => 'oracle',
       'host' => env('ORACLE_HOST', ''),
       'port' => env('ORACLE_PORT', '1521'),
       'database' => env('ORACLE_DATABASE', ''),
       'service_name' => env('ORACLE_SERVICE_NAME', ''),
       'username' => env('ORACLE_USERNAME', ''),
       'password' => env('ORACLE_PASSWORD', ''),
       'charset' => 'utf8',
   ],
   ```

   ],
3. Runned php artisan config:cache but with no result, except for this:

[image]

OR if i remove from mysql:

[image]

so it always aim to a mysql connection even if it's not specfied.
 Is there any other cache file to consider or something similar?

Comment: i always use this
https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need don't need to change DB_CONNECTION to ORACLE_CONNECTION.

```
DB_CONNECTION=oracle
DB_TNS=magrathea
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=heartofgold
DB_USERNAME=marvin
DB_PASSWORD=fortytw0
```

Please see full description hope you get help from this.
http://broncodev.com/2017-06-18-laravel5-oracle/

Comment: i thought that env vars, where vars in fact, and the name was irrelevant, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for select the answer and up voting. I'm glad it helped.